Parsing or exploding a list of dictionaries in a dataframe
I have a dataframe with lists of nested dictionaries that want to unpack.
I need to get the date and price from the priceHistory and the items listed in both WaterConservation and EnergyEfficient. The sample below is only two rows of a much larger dataframe where there are not the same number of dictionary items per dataframe row.
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[19, [{'priceChangeRate': 0, 'date': '2015-05-29', 'source': 'Public Record', 'postingIsRental': False, 'time': 1432857600000, 'sellerAgent': None, 'showCountyLink': False, 'attributeSource': {'infoString2': 'Public Record', 'infoString3': None, 'infoString1': None}, 'pricePerSquareFoot': 275, 'buyerAgent': None, 'event': 'Sold', 'price': 877205}], ['Low flow commode', 'Low flow fixtures', 'Water-Smart Landscaping'],''],
     [89, [{'priceChangeRate': 0.090909090909091, 'date': '2023-07-14', 'source': 'Public Record', 'postingIsRental': False, 'time': 1689292800000, 'sellerAgent': {'name': 'seller1', 'photo': {'url': 'https://sellerphoto1.jpg'}, 'profileUrl': '/profile/sellerprofile1/'}, 'showCountyLink': False, 'attributeSource': {'infoString2': 'Public Record', 'infoString3': None, 'infoString1': None}, 'pricePerSquareFoot': 308, 'buyerAgent': {'name': 'buyer1', 'photo': {'url': 'https://buyerphoto1.jpg'}, 'profileUrl': '/profile/buyerprofile1/'}, 'event': 'Sold', 'price': 1200000}, {'priceChangeRate': 0, 'date': '2015-08-20', 'source': 'Public Record', 'postingIsRental': False, 'time': 1440028800000, 'sellerAgent': None, 'showCountyLink': False, 'attributeSource': {'infoString2': 'Public Record', 'infoString3': None, 'infoString1': None}, 'pricePerSquareFoot': 50, 'buyerAgent': None, 'event': 'Sold', 'price': 195000}],'', ['Windows', 'Insulation', 'HVAC', 'Appliances', 'Lighting']]],
    columns=['id', 'priceHistory', 'WaterConservation', 'EnergyEfficient'])

I have tried too many things to list here, but this seems to be the most efficient (just to get priceHistory) (source):
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        df.pop("priceHistory").apply(
            lambda x: pd.Series({k: v for d in x for k, v in d.items()})
        ),
    ],
    axis=1,
)
print(df)


But I get this error:
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

what is your expected output

@iBeMeltin, I need the data in the lists to do further analysis. I should have stated that in the original post. The solution posted below works for my needs.

You can use Series.explode with json_normalize, creste same index by DataFrame.set_index, so possible use DataFrame.join:
s = df.pop('priceHistory').explode()
out = df.join(pd.json_normalize(s).set_index(s.index))


print (out)
   id                                  WaterConservation  \
0  19  [Low flow commode, Low flow fixtures, Water-Sm...   
1  89                                                      
1  89                                                      

                                     EnergyEfficient  priceChangeRate  \
0                                                            0.000000   
1  [Windows, Insulation, HVAC, Appliances, Lighting]         0.090909   
1  [Windows, Insulation, HVAC, Appliances, Lighting]         0.000000   

         date         source  postingIsRental           time  sellerAgent  \
0  2015-05-29  Public Record            False  1432857600000          NaN   
1  2023-07-14  Public Record            False  1689292800000          NaN   
1  2015-08-20  Public Record            False  1440028800000          NaN   

   showCountyLink  pricePerSquareFoot  buyerAgent event    price  \
0           False                 275         NaN  Sold   877205   
1           False                 308         NaN  Sold  1200000   
1           False                  50         NaN  Sold   195000   

  attributeSource.infoString2 attributeSource.infoString3  \
0               Public Record                        None   
1               Public Record                        None   
1               Public Record                        None   

  attributeSource.infoString1 sellerAgent.name     sellerAgent.photo.url  \
0                        None              NaN                       NaN   
1                        None          seller1  https://sellerphoto1.jpg   
1                        None              NaN                       NaN   

     sellerAgent.profileUrl buyerAgent.name     buyerAgent.photo.url  \
0                       NaN             NaN                      NaN   
1  /profile/sellerprofile1/          buyer1  https://buyerphoto1.jpg   
1                       NaN             NaN                      NaN   

     buyerAgent.profileUrl  
0                      NaN  
1  /profile/buyerprofile1/  
1                      NaN  


Thank you @jezrael, this works for what I need.

You can use the pd.json_normalize to get to get the date and price information from priceHistory. Then drop priceHistory column if you don't need it and join data and price to main df.
For instance:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[19, [{'priceChangeRate': 0, 'date': '2015-05-29', 'source': 'Public Record', 'postingIsRental': False, 'time': 1432857600000, 'sellerAgent': None, 'showCountyLink': False, 'attributeSource': {'infoString2': 'Public Record', 'infoString3': None, 'infoString1': None}, 'pricePerSquareFoot': 275, 'buyerAgent': None, 'event': 'Sold', 'price': 877205}], ['Low flow commode', 'Low flow fixtures', 'Water-Smart Landscaping'],''],
     [89, [{'priceChangeRate': 0.090909090909091, 'date': '2023-07-14', 'source': 'Public Record', 'postingIsRental': False, 'time': 1689292800000, 'sellerAgent': {'name': 'seller1', 'photo': {'url': 'https://sellerphoto1.jpg'}, 'profileUrl': '/profile/sellerprofile1/'}, 'showCountyLink': False, 'attributeSource': {'infoString2': 'Public Record', 'infoString3': None, 'infoString1': None}, 'pricePerSquareFoot': 308, 'buyerAgent': {'name': 'buyer1', 'photo': {'url': 'https://buyerphoto1.jpg'}, 'profileUrl': '/profile/buyerprofile1/'}, 'event': 'Sold', 'price': 1200000}, {'priceChangeRate': 0, 'date': '2015-08-20', 'source': 'Public Record', 'postingIsRental': False, 'time': 1440028800000, 'sellerAgent': None, 'showCountyLink': False, 'attributeSource': {'infoString2': 'Public Record', 'infoString3': None, 'infoString1': None}, 'pricePerSquareFoot': 50, 'buyerAgent': None, 'event': 'Sold', 'price': 195000}],'', ['Windows', 'Insulation', 'HVAC', 'Appliances', 'Lighting']]],
    columns=['id', 'priceHistory', 'WaterConservation', 'EnergyEfficient'])

price_history_df = pd.json_normalize(df['priceHistory'].explode().tolist(), sep='_')

df = df.drop('priceHistory', axis=1).join(price_history_df[['date', 'price']], how='left')

